# Cross platform coding \r\n vs \n

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

We are collaborating on a project with several team members who are using Mac, Windows and Unix based systems. I am curious if text can be configured to issue a \n instead of a \r\n at an end of line on a windows system to conform to unix standards? We are using UTF8

Comment: you can output the file as binary. Except for end of line character, opening the file in binary and text mode results the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Add the following to your preferences file, or to the shared `.sublime-project` file:

```json
"default_line_ending": "unix"
```

This overrides the default value of `"system"`. Note that this is only for new files. To change the line endings in an existing file, go to `View -> Line Endings` and select `Unix`.